# Vim Statusline - Virtualenv Function

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have just add virtualenv to vim. I want to have the active virtualenv show in the statusline so I know which environment I am in.

From Virtualenv help

```
g:virtualenv_stl_format 
    Format string for the statusline

Example:
    let g:virtualenv_stl_format = '[%n]'

To sue the statusline flag, this must appear in your 'statusline' setting
    %{virtualenv#statusline()}
```

So I went searching for the statusline and found
[writing a valid statusline](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Writing_a_valid_statusline)

They are going way beyond what I am trying to do and I really don't understand. I just want to simply add %{virtualenv#statusline()} to whatever line it is I have now, how do I do that?

The plugin I am referencing is this one https://github.com/jmcantrell/vim-virtualenv#readme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its simplest form, your statusline could be reduced to this line in your `~/.vimrc` (note the `=`):

```
set statusline=%{virtualenv#statusline()}
```

---

If you want that information to be displayed at the end of your current statusline, paste the following line in your `~/.vimrc` (note the `+=`):

```
set statusline+=%{virtualenv#statusline()}
```

Or to place it at the beginning (note the `^=`):

```
set statusline^=%{virtualenv#statusline()}
```

---

If you want to place this information at some arbitrary position in your custom statusline, you'll simply need to edit the corresponding line(s) in your `~/.vimrc`. But you already know how to do that since you already have a custom statusline, do you?

---

If you use the default statusline, you'll need to replicate it as per the example given in `:help statusline`:

```
set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

and place the virtualenv snippet at the desired location, say after the status flags:

```
set statusline=%<%f\ %h%m%r%{virtualenv#statusline()}%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

But all that is clearly explained in `:help statusline`.

Comment: No don't have a custom status line yet. I was using the virtualenv plugin and by default you don't know if its done anything so wanted the feedback showing in the statusline

Comment: Ok, follow the last method, then.